# java object creation and destruction

Tags: java, android, memory

I have a big bitmap, created with `Bitmap.createBitmap()`. Is there any sense in writing

```
bitmap = null;
```

just before

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap();
```

to let the GC use the memory occupied with the old bitmap while constructing the new bitmap.

The API level is 11.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your android version

Comment: If really immediately before: no, there is no sense there. GC will know it.

Comment: @Raghunandan Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @Axel http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. If it 2.3.3 and lower the calling recyle() on bitmap is necessary on 3.0 and higher bitmaps pixel data is stored on the heap

Comment: absolutely none whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

`bitamp = null;` will not ensure that GC will release the memory occupied by bitmap object. Brcause
as Bitmap is a final class so priority of final object is very low for GC. Use `bitmap.recycle()` method to ensure for Garbage collection(GC).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Look at the video around 11:23. The guy talks about bitmap memory management

Its left to the garbage collector to free memory. Instead of `bitmap = null` use `bitmap.recycle()` on andorid 2.3.3 and lower. Use `BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap` on 3.0 and higher

[Android - Bitmap and memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996655/android-bitmap-and-memory-management)

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

On android 2.3.3 and lower

**On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, using recycle() is recommended**. If you're displaying large amounts of bitmap data in your app, you're likely to run into OutOfMemoryError errors. The recycle() method allows an app to reclaim memory as soon as possible.

On android 3.0 and higher

The bitmap pixel data is stored on the heap

**Android 3.0 (API Level 11) introduces the BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap field. If this option is set, decode methods that take the Options object will attempt to reuse an existing bitmap when loading content**. **This means that the bitmap's memory is reused**, resulting in improved performance, and removing both memory allocation and de-allocation.

Also check this might help

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html